# Fetch an attribute in my model by providing the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i fetch in a model a method that would return the value of a specific model.

The code is has follow

Model Article

```
def article_title(id)
    art = Article.find_by_id(id)
    return art.title
end
```

The view is as follow

```
<% arttitle = Article.article_title(id) %>
```

This doesn't work but i am not sure what the way to do it

Comment: what do not work ? is there an error ?

Comment: Its when i call it, it say undefined article_title is undefined

Comment: this is really bad practice. Maybe tell us why you feel you have to look the title up via the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be defined as a class method, with `self` keyword

```
def self.article_title(id)
    Article.find(id).title
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You've defined an instance method, which should actually work if you called it on an article instance (but that wouldn't make much sense, design-wise). Define it as `self.article_title(id)` to make it a class method.

Also, it's generally not good practice to define variables and perform lookups in your views. Views are templates to display information - nothing more. The more your business logic is spread through your app in unpredictable ways, the harder it will be to develop and change in the future.

Comment: I agree, but its the only way i can see all the information required